# Hadoop: Implement a nested for loop in MapReduce [Java]

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement a statistical formula that requires comparing a datapoint with all other possible datapoints. For example my dataset is something like:

```
10.22
15.77
16.55
9.88
```

I need to go through this file like:

```
for (i=0;i< data.length();i++)
   for (j=0;j< data.length();j++)
     Sum +=(data[i] + data[j])
```

Basically when i get each line through my map function, i need to execute some instructions on the rest of the file in the reducer like in a nested for loop. 
Now i have tried using the distributedCache, some form of ChainMapper but to no avail. Any idea of how i can go about doing this would be really appreciated. Even an out of the box way will be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate your example please, like add a couple of lines and then show an example with one data point

Comment: Like a simple example where 10.22 is first point, 15.77 is second point. So i=0(10.22) and j=0(10.22) then 1(15.77) then 2(16.55) then 3(9.88). So for each value of a point in the dataset go through all remaining points in the dataset.

Comment: So for every row in the file, you need to iterate over the entire file, Have i understood the problem correctly ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if this problem is suited for the map reduce paradigm, If you have 100's of such files and you want to parallelize it from a file perspective then this can be done. But from the perspective of a single file the problem is not splittable, it cannot be solved using a divide and conquer approach.

To process each element in the file you need to access the entire file, so any algorithm that you use will need you to hold the entire file in memory if this is acceptable then we could have multiple solutions including the one stated below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the run method implementation of the Reducer Class.

```
 public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  setup(context);
  while (context.nextKey()) {
     //This corresponds to the ones corresponding to i of first iterator
    Text currentKey = context.getCurrentKey();
    Iterator<VALUEIN> currentValue = context.getValues();
    if(context.nextKey()){
     //You can get the Next Values the ones corresponding to j of you second iterator
    }
}
cleanup(context);
```

}

or if you don't have reducer you can do the same in the Mapper as well by overriding the

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
setup(context);
while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
 /*context.nextKeyValue() if invoked again gives you the next key values which is same as the ones you are looking for in the second loop*/
}
cleanup(context);
```

}

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Let me test it when i wake up in the morning.